# Convert wireless Time Machine to wired

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have been using the Time Machine backup utility wirelessly. I'd now like switch to wired. How do I do that? What problems should I expect?

Comment: You mean connecting via an Ethernet cable?

Comment: more details please. Do you use a Time machine capsule and would like to connect with a cable in the future?

Answer (score 3):

1. Turn off wifi
2. Plug in Ethernet
3. Test a backup and restore a file it two

   You should expect no problems whatsoever, you should expect significantly faster response times